# How to automatically change the signature of overridden methods when the signature of the virtual method change with MSV2008 in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, parameters, refactoring

I have a virtual method which is overridden many times. I would like to add a parameter to all these methods.

Can we just add a parameter to the virtual method and use a refactor for automatically updating all overridden methods ?

I know it is possible to Remove or Reorder parameters with the refactor, but I don't find Add.

Comment: you may want to have a look at one of the more full-featured refactoring add-ins for Visual Studio, such as CodeRush or ReSharper

Comment: The simple free solution would be to do this by hand.  Shouldn't take anyone with any ounce of talent a very short amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality is not included in Visual Studio.

As was mentioned in a comment, I believe you can get that by installing a plugin such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (see the documentation on [changing method signatures](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html)).

If you don't want install a plugin (like me), I use Visual Studio's feature to Find All References (by right-clicking on the function, or using the hotkey Ctrl + K, R). That at least makes it easier to do: simply double-click on each search result and make the change.

Comment: Thank you. I use Resharper like you & jeroenh says with the 30 days free. But in the future I will make like you.